# Is there a word for 'using what you have learnt'?

Tags: single-word-requests

Does a word for '**using what you have learnt**' (or with a similar meaning) exist in the English language?

I looked up on Google and reverse-search dictionaries, but haven't come across such a term.

I intend to use the word instead of the blank in the following semi-example:

> She has the ability to `____` and apply her knowledge in real life.

Comment: I presume you are looking for a verb.  Am I right?

Comment: A verb is preferable. A noun may be acceptable as well.

Comment: It's not a single word but a phrase, which is why I'm making it a comment rather than an answer. But one of the nicest idiomatic phrases I've seen to describe this came from an Asimov novella entitled "Profession", namely "*oiling the stiff knowledge*". The entire text of the story is here (it's a great read): http://agilitator.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/profession.pdf and the relevant quote is on page 32 of 56.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use ***[exploit](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/exploit)***:

> - to utilize, esp. for profit; turn to practical account: *to exploit a natural talent*.

or the expression:

[make the most of](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/make+the+most+of):.

> - to exploit something; to get as much out of something as is possible. Mary knows how to make the most of her talents. *They designed the advertisements to make the most of the product's features.*

The Free Dictionary

Comment: This is what I needed. You are of a great help, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Consider, ***exercise*** [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=exercise+his+knowledge&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cexercise%20his%20knowledge%3B%2Cc0)

> : to put in practice; to carry out in action; to perform the duties of; to use; to employ; to practice [machaut.uchicago.edu](http://machaut.uchicago.edu/?action=search&resource=Webster%27s&word=Exercise&quicksearch=on)
>
> *She has the ability to exercise and apply her knowledge in real life*.

Answer (score 1):

***Implement*** used as a verb means to use experience or concepts in a practical sense. As a noun Implement describes a tool or object used as a tool; "Implements of destruction" meaning picks and shovels, via Arlo Guthrie.